# dialogic diva + vmware esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have installed ESXi 4.1 at a HP server:
HP ProLiant DL 380G6 with 2 x Intel Xeon X5650

Everything works correctly and without problem.

I need to install a Dialogic Diva120PRI PCIe EURO board and then I need to assign it to a virtual server.

After installing the card server recognized the card and I applied pass-through.

I've added this device to guest WinXP32Pro VMashine and installed Diva drivers (DivaAll.exe 6.00.3790.0)

But in process of the first reboot to applying settings a have BSOD like this:

http://s008.radikal.ru/i306/1012/f9/b503a49babd2.png

Is there the way to fix this problem?

Have anybody met this situation?

Thank you forward.

Comment: What EXACT model of server do you have and what is/are it's processor/s? - edit: we can't help you if you don't respond to questions.

Comment: Sorry I was off for some days. I have HP ProLiant DL 380G6
with 2 x Intel Xeon X5650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for coming back to me with details, although that machine is vt-d compatible the card you're using isn't listed as a supported board my VMWare for DirectPath I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks!
And one more subquestions. As I got this situation is OS-independent? Linux won't get me nothing?

Comment: Unlikely sorry, the guest OS sees it as a hardware fault.